# How to check selected time in specified range?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i have Booking page which contains Date picker and time picker and one button.if user click that button we need to check that selected date and time whether  match shop day and time if it's not match i need to show message which should say pls select time with in this(for example:thursday: 09:10AM - 06:30PM).here i have get day from date and here already we are having shop open time and close time

```
Day: {                   
    "monday"    : "09:10AM  -  06:30PM",
    "tuesday"   : "09:10AM  -  06:30PM",
    "wednesday" : "09:10AM  -  06:30PM",
    "thursday"  : "09:10AM  -  06:30PM",
    "friday"    : "09:10AM  -  06:30PM",
    "saturday"  : "10:15AM  -  04:15PM",
    "sunday"    : "10:15AM  -  04:15PM"
    },
```

i have not added date and time picker Assume if user selected below condtion
For example. 1.if i select date(02/12/2015),controller i got day(Wednesday) through the date and user selected time 11:00am i need to check with shop day(which is mentioned above).selected day and time match between shop open and close time so we dont want to show any message bcoz user selected correct time .
2.if i select date(03/12/2015),controller i got day(Thursday) through the date and user selected time 08:00pm i need to check with shop day(which is mentioned above).selected day and time does not match between shop open and close time so here i need to put alert and it will show (sorry shop closed now ,shop open time:09:10AM and shop closed time:06:30PM pls select time between this).
i am new to programming i am trying since 3 days for this pls help me out .

```
$scope.check=function(){

//Assume This is Shop details We need to check with this data 
  $scope.dealers = [{

        S_Email_id: "aditiya@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "samsung",
        status:"",
        Store_Name: "Adtiya Samsung Store",
        S_Services: "Regular Service,Software Faults,Hardware Faults",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles",
        Day: {
        "monday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "tuesday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "wednesday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "thursday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "friday": "09:10AM - 06:30PM",
        "saturday": "10:15AM - 04:15PM",
        "sunday":"10:15AM - 04:15PM"
        },
    }];

    //Condtion one 
        var sdate =userselecteddate;
        console.log(sdate);
        //here i am getting Wed Dec 02 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
        var dayNames = new Array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
        var nData = new Date(sdate);
        console.log(dayNames[nData.getDay()]);
        //Wednesday

        var stime=userselectedtime;
        console.log(stime);//11:00am

        //Condtion Two 
        var sdate =userselecteddate;
        console.log(sdate);
        //here i am getting Thu Dec 03 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
        var dayNames = new Array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
        var nData = new Date(sdate);
        console.log(dayNames[nData.getDay()]);
        //Thursday

        var stime=userselectedtime;
        console.log(stime);
        //08:00pm



        //cheching code 


}
```

above i have shown based on condtion what i am getting in console help me out to move forward

Answer (score 0):

After you have captured the date and time values that the user has input, given that those values are stored in `$scope` somehow:

```
$scope.isValidDate = function isValidDateFn(dateVal) {
  //Logic here that returns whether or not you have a valid time;
  return booleanThatIsTrueOrFalseBasedOnTheOfficeHours;
};

$scope.isValidTime = function isValidTimeFn(timeVal) {
  return booleanThatIsTrueOrFalseBasedOnTheOfficeOpenDays;
};

$scope.isValidOfficeDateTimeSubmission = function isValidOfficeDateTimeSubmissionFn(dateString, timeString) {
  var validTime = $scope.isValidTime(timeString),
      validDate = $scope.isValidDate(dateString);

  var validationObject = {
      errors: [], 
      valid: validTime && validDate
  }

  if (!validTime) {
     validationObject.errors.push("Invalid Time Message With Whatever Else You Want To Put In Here")
  }

  if (!validDate) {
     validationObject.errors.push("Invalid Date Message With Whatever Else You Want To Put In Here")
  }


  return validationObject
};
```

The logic is for you to determine, however this is a pretty decent approach to being able to retrieve both error messages or just one type if needed through the validationObject. You would then have a scope function that is called via `ng-click` that runs this, checks the `valid` property of your `validationObject` returned from `isValidOfficeDateAndTimeSubmission` function and then performs whatever error display, success, etc, based on the contents of the validation object.

```
$scope.userDidAttemptToSubmitDateTime = function userDidAttemptToSubmitDateTimeFn(){
  //Given that your date and time live in $scope.
  var validationObject = $scope.isValidOfficeDateTimeSubmission($scope.dateVarBoundFromInputInHTML, $scope.timeVarBoundFromInputInHTML); 

  //Now use the properties in your validationObject to do whatever the heck you want to show the user

 if (validationObject.errors.length) {
   $scope.showErrorsToUserWithArbitraryErrorStringArray(validationObject.errors);
 } else {
   $scope.showSuccessfulSelectionMessageWithPotentialCallbackIfYouWantedTo(callBackFn);
 }
}
```

Comment: can you pls add jsfiddle for me bcoze i didt not understand